# Nielsen & Chuang Exercise 2.32: Show that the tensor product of two projectors is a projector

Tags: mathematics, nielsen-and-chuang, textbook-and-exercises

$\newcommand{\bra}[1]{\left<#1\right|}
\newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left|#1\right>}$Here is what I tried:

Given that we have two projectors:
$$
A = \sum_i \ket{i} \bra{i}, \hspace{2em}
B = \sum_j \ket{j} \bra{j}
$$
The goal is to prove that:
$$
A \otimes B = \sum_k \ket{k} \bra{k}. \tag1\label1
$$
Plugging into \eqref{1}, we get:
$$
A \otimes B
= \left( \sum_i \ket{i} \bra{i} \right) \otimes \left( \sum_j \ket{j} \bra{j} \right)
= \sum_{i,j} \ket{i} \bra{i} \otimes \ket{j} \bra{j}
\tag{2}\label{2}
$$
I'm not sure how to proceed from \eqref{2}. It would be convenient if for every $\ket{i}$ and $\ket{j}$ there is a $\ket{k}$ for which the following identity is true:
$$
\ket{k} \bra{k} = \ket{i} \bra{i} \otimes \ket{j} \bra{j} \tag{3}\label{3}
$$
This would prove \eqref{1} immediately. Is \eqref{3} true though? If yes, why? If not, how else can we proceed to prove \eqref{1}?

Comment: it's just a redefinition. More precisely you should write $|k\rangle=|i,j\rangle$. The only identity you are using is $|i\rangle\!\langle i|\otimes\lvert j\rangle\!\langle j\rvert=\lvert i,j\rangle\!\langle i,j\rvert$

Comment: Thanks, that answers my question. I tried proving $|i\rangle\!\langle i|\otimes\lvert j\rangle\!\langle j\rvert=\lvert i,j\rangle\!\langle i,j\rvert$ and managed to convince myself of its truth by expanding the terms into matrices/vectors and see what gets multiplied by what, but I'm wondering if there's a "nicer" way to do this. I tried looking at the definitions in Nielsen & Chuang (10th edition) page 73 but couldn't find anything useful, which is weird because the book usually introduces the necessary identities prior to the exercises.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wouldn't approach the problem the way that you have. Instead, I'd take the definition of what it means to be a projector: $P$ is a projector if and only if $P^2=P$ and $P=P^\dagger$.

So, let's take
$$
P=P_A\otimes P_B.
$$
We can calculate $P^\dagger=P_A^\dagger\otimes P_B^\dagger=P_A\otimes P_B=P$, which follows from the assumption that $P_A$ and $P_B$ are projectors.

Similarly,
$$
P^2=P_A^2\otimes P_B^2=P_A\otimes P_B=P.
$$
You're done!

Answer (score -1):

$\begin{aligned} {[A \otimes B](|a\rangle \otimes|b\rangle) } &=\left[\sum_i|i\rangle\langle i|\otimes \sum_j| j\rangle\langle j|\right](|a\rangle \otimes|b\rangle) \\ 
&=\left[\sum_i|i\rangle\langle i \mid a\rangle\right] \otimes\left[\sum_i|j\rangle\langle j \mid b\rangle\right] \\ 
&=\sum_{i, j}\langle i | a\rangle\langle j \mid b\rangle(|i\rangle \otimes|j\rangle) \\ 
&=\sum_{i, j}\langle i j \mid a b\rangle|i j\rangle \\ 
&=\left[\sum_{i, j}|i j\rangle\langle i j|\right]|a\rangle \otimes|b\rangle \end{aligned}$

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).